# What can i use to interact with the search bar on this website using cypress

Tags: automation, cypress, web-testing, webautomation

I am trying to complete a test case that involved opening propertypal.com, entering some values and validating the responses using the software cypress. I've never used cypress before but the company asking me to do this test want me to utilise it.
This is the website i'm testing https://www.propertypal.com/

I want to type bt6 into that text box, but I cant work out the correct locator to use. Everything I try either returns multiple elements or doesn't find anything.
Below are some of the things I tried with no success. The main things I have been honing in on are the placeholder text, the ID and element name.

I'm very new to this type of automation so any help would be amazing.

```
cy.get('query').type('bt6')
cy.get('input:first').should('have.attr', 'placeholder', 'Search Area, Address, Agent').click()
cy.get('search-form-textbox').type('bt6')
```

Comment: Here is the element i'm trying to identify
<input id="query" type="text" name="q" class="search-form-textbox" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" value="" placeholder="Search Area, Address, Agent" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off">

Answer (score 2):

With this element

```html
<input id="query" 
  type="text" 
  name="q" 
  class="search-form-textbox" 
  autocorrect="off" 
  spellcheck="false" 
  value="" 
  placeholder="Search Area, Address, Agent">
```

Using the id="query" should be best,

```js
cy.get('input#query')                // should only be one id "query" on the page
  .type('bt6');
```

If there's multiple id's "query" and you want to flag it,

```js
cy.get('input#query')          
  .then($els => {
    expect($els.length).to.eq(1)    // assert there's only one id found, otherwise fail
  })
  .type('bt6');
```

If there's multiple id's "query" and you don't really care, you can select the third which is the visible one.

```js
cy.get('input#query')          
  .eq(2)                           // take the third, which is at center of the page
  .type('bt6');
```

Taking the "nth" element found is always a bit fragile, but placeholder text is pretty good instead (provided the page isn't multi-lingual)

```js
cy.get('input[placeholder="Search Area, Address, Agent"]')  // easier with attribute in selector
  .eq(1)                           // take the second, as the are two of these
  .type('bt6');
```

Class is not so good, as can often be applied to multiple elements, but in this case it's pretty good because it's specific to the role,

```js
cy.get('input.search-form-textbox') // prefix class with "."
  .eq(2)                            // take the third, which is at center of the page
  .type('bt6')
```

Comment: There are three `#query` ids on the page, the first two are hidden behind menus. If you take the third with `cy.get('#query').eq(2)` it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the command to handle multiple results from each of the selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Web pages can often have multiple elements with the same selector, for example `cy.get('input#query')` has three elements with this id.

What happens is the developer creates a component, adds an id like `<input id="query">` then adds the component in several places, so the page actually ends up with multiple ids of the same name.

When the page is complex with hidden sections, to find the element you want start by testing with a console.log

```js
cy.get('input#query')    // finds 3 elements
  .then(console.log)     // log them to dev tools
```

Open dev tools, click open the object printed and you can see the list of elements selected.

[image]

Now you can hover each element, and the corresponding element on the page is highlighted.

[image]

In this case the first two are hidden behind menu items, but the third is the one we need.

So now we can add an `.eq(2)` to select the third element

```js
cy.get('input#query')    // finds 3 elements
  .eq(2)                 // take the third element
  .type('bt6');
```

Answer (score 0):

So when I ran the cypress Test for your website, I got an uncaught exception that is originating from your Application. This is something that should be analyzed and is possibly fixed.

[image: Exception]

If this is something that is not going to be fixed, then you can add the below in your test, so that cypress ignores the exception and doesn't throw an error.

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    return false
  })
```

Now I tried using the locator id(#query) to input the test, as it is always good to use id because it's unique, but unfortunately, it gave me an error as the element is not visible. Unfortunately adding `{force: true}` also didn't help me solve the issue.

```
cy.get('#query').type('bt6')
```

[image: Error due to using id as Query]

1.So, the locator that worked for me was `.search-ctrl`. So your Final Test will look like this:

```
cy.visit('https://www.propertypal.com/')
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    return false
  })
cy.get('.search-ctrl').type('bt6')
```

2.Now, if you want to globally handle the exception, then go to `cypress/support/index.js` and then write there:

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
    return false
  })
```

And then in this case your test will just have:

```
cy.visit('https://www.propertypal.com/')
cy.get('.search-ctrl').type('bt6')
```

[image: Successful Execution]